# Is there any function that will find all the anchor elements from a webpage and get all the css selectors of that elements in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to click all the anchor tags which are present on the page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" class="abc">SUCCESS</a>
<a href="#" class="abc1">SUCCESS</a>
<a href="#" class="abc2">SUCCESS</a>
<a href="#" class="abc65">SUCCESS</a>
<a href="#" class="abc76">SUCCESS</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below snippet for clicking each anchor tags.
And its not possible to get all the attributes of the element.

```
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a"));
    for (WebElement ele : links) {
        ele.click();
        //go back to previous page
    }
```